# HTML Disappears? Most complex bug I ever seen

Tags: html, angularjs, svg

I have the weirdest bug ever...

If I open my html file directly I can see all the html

But if I open it using my angularjs app from the index.html e.g. `#!/foo` part of the html does not display, always in the bottom of the page.

If you check the network tools, the div doesn't have any content:

[image]

But I have the HTML correct

[image]

After investigation, if I remove part of the SVGs that I have it starts to display it all again...

```
 <svg class="svg-star">
    <use xlink:href="#svg-star"></use>
 </svg>


// Bottom of the page

<svg style="display: none;">
<symbol id="svg-star" viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
    <polygon points="4.994,0.249 6.538,3.376 9.99,3.878 7.492,6.313 8.082,9.751 4.994,8.129 1.907,9.751 
2.495,6.313 -0.002,3.878 3.45,3.376 "/>
</symbol>
```

Any idea what might be?? I have like 10 SVGs in the page and I can see all of them and if I remove one it appears some of the html, if I remove another it appears a bit more...

My index.html

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app="GHoF">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-include="'app/pages/navBar/navBar.html'"></div>

    <div ng-include="'app/pages/sideMenu/sideMenu.html'"></div>

    <div ng-include="'app/pages/mainMenu/mainMenu.html'"></div>

    <main ng-view></main>

    <div ng-include="'app/pages/footer/footer.html'"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the missing closing `svg` tag in your first HTML snippet a copy/paste error  ?

Comment: yes, the svg tag is there

Comment: With `<svg>` elements, it is important to have the closing tag `</svg>`. It is best not to trust the parser to automatically close it.

Comment: Do your SVG files have duplicate id attributes? i.e. does the page have more than one id="svg-star" on it (or any other id).